# Using sql to retrieve a value 3 tables away

Tags: sql

I need some sql help please. I have the following (below) tables and table StaffRole is a join table between Staff and Role. I am trying to figure out the sql for getting the primary role for a particular StaffID. I have the StaffID as 12345, but dont have any other data. Can someone help me solve my query please.

```
Table: Staff
Field: StaffID

Table: StaffRole
Fields: StaffID, RoleID

Table: Role
Fields: RoleID, RoleTitle, Primary


SELECT ROLE.RoleTitle
FROM Role AS ROLE
LEFT JOIN Staff AS STAFF STAFF.StaffID = STAFFROLE.StaffID
LEFT JOIN StaffRole AS STAFFROLE ON ROLE.RoleID = STAFFROLE.RoleID
WHERE STAFF.StaffID = "12345" AND ROLE.Primary = "True"
```

Comment: I'm using FileMaker. Its just returning a question mark, so thought my query was at fault, however I walked through the code thinking it looks OK. I'll try rekeying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already a StaffId as input, you don't need the STAFF table:

```
SELECT ROLE.RoleTitle
FROM Role AS ROLE
  LEFT JOIN StaffRole AS STAFFROLE ON ROLE.RoleID = STAFFROLE.RoleID
WHERE STAFFROLE.StaffID = '12345' AND ROLE.Primary = 'True'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your joins are out of order. In SQL Server it throws an error because of the reference to STAFF ROLE before it was joined. Change to

```
SELECT ROLE.RoleTitle
FROM Role AS ROLE
LEFT JOIN StaffRole AS STAFFROLE ON ROLE.RoleID = STAFFROLE.RoleID
LEFT JOIN Staff AS STAFF STAFF.StaffID = STAFFROLE.StaffID
WHERE STAFF.StaffID = "12345" AND ROLE.Primary = True"
```